# Worklight 6.1.0.01 - JSONStore issue on Android 2.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

After upgrading Worklight 6.1 to the last version (v 6.1.0.01 release on 11/03/2014), our application has stopped working on Android 2.3 when the JSONStore is initialized.
We have create a test application in order to reproduce the error. After the test application is started, we initialized the JSONStore with a simple colletion.

```
var collections = {};
//Object that defines the 'people' collection
collections["people"] = {};
//Object that defines the Search Fields for the 'people' collection
WL.JSONStore.init(collections)
.then(function () {
//success function
})
.fail(function (errorObject) {
//error function
});
```

The log on our Android 2.3 device reports the following lines when the JSONStore is initialized:

> 01-18 14:57:11.419: D/com.test(1694): Extracting zip file: featurelibs/armeabi/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.609: D/com.test(1694): Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.test/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.739: I/DEBUG(88): *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** ***
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.739: I/DEBUG(88): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-S5830/GT-S5830:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD/XWKTS:user/release-keys'
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.739: I/DEBUG(88): pid: 1694, tid: 1704  >>> com.test <<<
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.739: I/DEBUG(88): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 80c86cc4
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.739: I/DEBUG(88):  r0 80db8e18  r1 47609324  r2 80d7997c  r3 00000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.739: I/DEBUG(88):  r4 80dc0354  r5 00000001  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  r8 802182c0  r9 00219228  10 46072cac  fp 46e46fbc
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  ip 0000004f  sp 47609330  lr afd1d1b3  pc 80c86cc4  cpsr 60000010
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d0  41dd402807c00000  d1  41dd402807800000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d2  000000003f000000  d3  000000003f000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d8  4130000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.749: I/DEBUG(88):  scr 20000012
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):          #00  pc 00086cc4  /data/data/com.test/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): #01  pc 0001d1ae  /system/lib/libc.so
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): code around pc:
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): 80c86ca4 e1a01006 ebff0215 e59f3104 e59d2004
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): 80c86cb4 e7923003 e5830000 eaffffee e59d0004
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): 80c86cc4 e30f6b27 e59f20e8 e34f6fff e5846108
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): 80c86cd4 e1a01003 e790c002 e28d0020 e3a02010
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): 80c86ce4 e58c3000 ebff01d2 e59f30c8 e28d1024
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): code around lr:
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): afd1d190 bdf0b003 783718c6 2f3d1c70 e7ecd1f1
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): afd1d1a0 000243f2 ffffff4c b083b500 f7ffa901
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): afd1d1b0 b003ffbb 46c0bd00 1c04b510 fca4f7ff
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): afd1d1c0 886388a1 18c00408 46c0bd10 1c0db5f8
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): afd1d1d0 1c081c04 1c161c11 e8bcf7f0 1c071c31
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88): stack:
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     476092f0  003b1310
>   01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     476092f4  003b15a8
>   01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     476092f8  0000000b
>   01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     476092fc  802a1ce8
>   01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     47609300  802a1ce8
>   01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     47609304  0000000e
>   01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     47609308  b000e548
>   01-18 14:57:12.809: I/DEBUG(88):     4760930c  80dc0354
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609310  00000001
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609314  00000000
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609318  00000000
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     4760931c  afd1d1b3  /system/lib/libc.so
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609320  ffffffff
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609324  80c47034  /data/data/com.test/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609328  df002777
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     4760932c  e3a070ad
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88): #01 47609330  b000e5d4
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609334  80db8e18
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609338  ffffffff
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     4760933c  00000000
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609340  b000e548
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609344  b00140cc
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609348  b000e548
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     4760934c  b00047a3  /system/bin/linker
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609350  ffffffff
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609354  b000e548
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609358  00001426
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     4760935c  000022a9
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609360  80db8734
>   01-18 14:57:12.819: I/DEBUG(88):     47609364  00000004
>   01-18 14:57:12.829: I/DEBUG(88):     47609368  00000004
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.829: I/DEBUG(88):     4760936c  b00037f5  /system/bin/linker
>
> 01-18 14:57:12.829: I/DEBUG(88):     47609370  b000e62c
>   01-18 14:57:12.829: I/DEBUG(88):     47609374  b000e628

The application is closed without an exception or an explicit error.

We have checked that the zip file “featurelibs/armeabi/libcrypto.so.1.0.0”  is present inside our apk, with also every other libraries needed .

Are we missing something?

Comment: Are you using the emulator for 2.3? If you run this app in another android version > 2.3 (either emulator or device) does it work?

Comment: What happens when you install Worklight v6.1.0.01 inside a clean eclispe with an empty workspace folder, create a hybrid application, enable jsonstore, add the init code you described above and run it on the same device or simulator (share version numbers)?

Comment: We have tested on a real device (Galaxy Ace - Android 2.3.6) and on the emulator (API 10 - Android 2.3.3). On a device with Android >2.3 the test application works fine, without any problem.

With a new workspace and a new installation of Worklight we have the same problem.

Comment: So it is only in the emulator that you get the error? I ask because there is a bug in the Android 2.3.x emulator when running Javascript code, and it could be interfering. More information: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987 The reason I'm not sure if that is the case is that it does not explicitly show that error. Also, have you tried in other 2.3.3 devices/emulators that are not the Galaxy Ace, to see if it is specific to that device?

Comment: Would you upload the project you created with an new empty workspace? Use the [this code inside main.js](https://gist.github.com/cnandreu/10496356). For what it's worth, I tried on a HTC Hero Running v2.3 using Worklight v6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 and it worked fine, the logcat output is [here](https://gist.github.com/cnandreu/10496531). Also, could provide the file size and [md5 hash](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+md5+hash+of+a+file+osx) of the `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` you're using?

Comment: @DanielGonzalez We tested on the simulator and on the device, and we have obtained the same error. We have only a Galaxy Ace for our test.

Comment: @cnandreu md5 hash for our lybcrypto.so.1.0.0 is feba9e040741fa488a5a96b355d8f06f (this value is calculated on Windows 7 with File Checksum Integrity Verifier (FCIV) utility)
I have created a new empty workspace, with your code inside main.js. The problem is the same, our app will close at line 51 of your logcat.

Comment: @ClaudiaFoglieni What virtual device configuration are you using for the emulator? That way I can try to reproduce it with the same configuration.

Comment: @DanielGonzalez Our configuration is:
`avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
abi.type=armeabi
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=none
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:eac90e1b0be121e39ffd48020616352b
hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
hw.device.name=3.2in QVGA (ADP2)
hw.gps=yes
hw.keyboard=no
hw.lcd.density=160
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.ramSize=512
hw.sdCard=no
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=yes
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=320x480
skin.path=320x480
vm.heapSize=16`

Answer (score 1):

@Claudia: Support for Android Emulator 2.3.x IBM Worklight does not support Android Emulator 2.3.x because of known issues, as detailed in the Android list of issues at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list (search for issue 12987).

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html

There are workarounds as noted by the android ticket but it may not be feasible for your purposes.

Comment: thanks for pointing this limitation out. 
Do you know if there is something about the problem on a real device in the official documentation? Because I haven't found nothing about problems with JSONStore and Android 2.3.x

Comment: No, not at the moment, unfortunately. I believe there is very little support for lower api for Android. If a problem does occur that effects JSONStore and Android it will be noted. Hope this helps.